# App Facebook live notification through firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-live-api

Is it possible to send out a notification to everyone who has downloaded an app (through firebase) every time someone starts a facebook live video?  I.e. not manually going into firebase and sending out a notification but as soon as they click start live video on their facebook app it sends a notification automatically to users of the app to tune in?

Comment: This is too broad of a question. You're not really supposed to ask "is it possible". Try it, read some documentation, fail a couple of times. Then come back with code samples and we will help.

Comment: I've read through the facebook live api documentation, been all over stackoverflow and youtube and haven't found anything like this.  So I was just wondering if it was at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question: Facebook Live API allows you to stream through your app, it also allows you to *GET* a `live_stream` object if you have the `live_video_id`, but you can't detect once a `live_stream` object is created.